# If I have a diagonal matrix, is it necessarily the product of two other diagonal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know that the product of two diagonal matrices forms another diagonal matrix, since we just multiply the entries.

So my question is, does the converse necessarily hold? In other words, if I have a diagonal matrix, did it necessarily come from the product of two other diagonal matrices?

My gut feeling tells me "No" since in Linear Algebra, all sorts of 'intuition' seem to go wrong.

But I would like a confirmation and perhaps a counter example would be nice.

Comment: Diagonal matrices act just like numbers when you add them or multiply them together.

Comment: Oh dear did I phrase my question poorly? What I had intended is in other words "Is it possible to construct a diagonal matrix using non diagonal square matrices?"

Comment: Then you should edit what you intended into your question. In particular, in the question title and at the end of the second sentence, *"two other diagonal matrices"* should read *"two non-diagonal square matrices"*.

Comment: After all I think the question is: "It is known that if $A$ and $B$ are both diagonal matrices, $D = AB$ is also a diagonal matrix. Does the converse also holds?"

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  Then the answer is *no*, as you suspected.  For a counterexample, a rotation matrix times its inverse yields the identity, but rotation matrices are not diagonal.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=?$ (To answer question from your comments, which is different from the question in your post.)

Comment: Trivially, $AA^{-1} = I$ for all invertible square matrices $A$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess we can easily arrive at a counter-example:

Let us take two $2 \times 2$  matrices and multiply them:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
e&f\\
g&h\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
ae+bg&af+bh\\
ce+dg&cf+dh\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now for the result to be a diagonal matrix:

$ce=-dg $ and $ af=-bh$

So resulting in :
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
ae+bg&0\\
0&cf+dh\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So Let us take an example as :

Let $\large c=1,d=-\dfrac{1}{2},e=1,g=2\space$ and $\large \space a=1,b=-\dfrac{1}{4},f=2,h=8$

Hence we arrive at:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-\dfrac{1}{4}\\
1&-\dfrac{1}{2}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\
2&8\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{2}&0\\
0&-2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

> Thus it is not always necessary to have two diagonal matrices give a diagonal matrix...

Hope this helps

Comment: Fixed multiplication Errors XD ... BTW please inform if there are any more errors... But this the general way of doing a lot of matrix and determinant examples during exams!

Comment: FTR, this doesn't really answer the OP – you're answering the question “if $A$ and $B$ are not diagonal, is it possible that $AB$ is diagonal nevertheless?” Perhaps that's what the OP actually _meant_, but really the question asks “if $D$ is diagonal, do there exist diagonal $A$ and $B$ such that $D = AB$?” That's quite a different matter, and is answered by the other posts.

Comment: @leftaroundabout No actually the OP stated that that's what he found ... " so is it always necessary that *it* be so? If not give a counter example " . (I **think** that's what he meant)

Answer (score 12):

If $D$ is diagonal then $D=ID$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. :)

Answer (score 4):

Of course yes, and there are infinitely many such decompositions $D = AB$. For each diagonal entry $d_i$, you just decompose it into a product $d_i = a_i b_i$ arbitrarily. Letting $A = diag(a_i)$ and $B = diag(b_i)$ you have $D=AB$.

For example, you can have $A = D$ and $B = I$.

Another example is $A = diag(\vert d_i \vert)$ and $B = diag(sgn(d_i))$.